# C++ question about iterating over std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

My question ("why it doesn't work?") concerns the small sample below.

When I run this (after `g++ testThis.cc -o testThis`) I get:

```
printing 101
printing 102
printing 103
                                 printing 100
                                 printing 100
                                 printing -1021296524
```

It should not be a problem of `myHolder` dropping out of scope, so why make a local copy of the vector itself?

It should stay cozy in the class itself.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class stdHolder {

public:

  stdHolder();

  std::vector<int> getSV() const {return _myVector;}

private:

  std::vector<int> _myVector;

};

stdHolder::stdHolder() {

  _myVector.push_back(1);
  _myVector.push_back(2);
  _myVector.push_back(3);

}

int main() {

  stdHolder myHolder;

  // the following works
  std::vector<int> localSV = myHolder.getSV();
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = localSV.begin(); it != localSV.end(); it++ ) {
    std::cout << "printing " << *it + 100 << std::endl;
  }

  //return 0; // comment this line to see my problem

  // the following loops forever
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = myHolder.getSV().begin(); it != myHolder.getSV().end(); it++ ) {
    std::cout << "                                 printing " << *it + 100 << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
```

Comment: `myHolder.getSV().begin()` and `myHolder.getSV().end()` work on different vectors.

Comment: `getSV()` returns a copy - so you get a new vector every time you call this function. Change the return type to `std::vector<int>&` to see it work properly

Comment: Or add `begin()` and `end()` member functions to `stdHolder`. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/h57vvjss3)

Comment: In general never call `.end()` in the condition portion of the loop, cache the result once in the setup. Function call overhead is not trivial and the standard requires that it assumes you've invalidated the iterator every single time so it can't fix that performance mistake.

Comment: @Mgetz Optimization may however notice that nothing will invalidate the `end()` iterator and then it can cache it anyway. Oh well, sidestep... :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo it can't cache it because `.end()` isn't pure

Comment: @Mgetz A `vector`'s `end()` is usually base pointer + size and unless the loop does anything to change the size, it can be cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question ("why it doesn't work?")

Because `myHolder.getSV().begin()` and `myHolder.getSV().end()` work on different vectors since you're calling the member function `stdHolder::getSV()` twice and for each invocation there will a different vector returned(as you're returning a vector **by value**).

That is, the iterator `it` is initialized with `myHolder.getSV().begin()` but then you're comparing `it`(pun intended) with the result of `myHolder.getSV().end()` which is an iterator to a completely different vector returned by the call `myHolder.getSV()`.

---

One way to solve this is by returning the vector by const reference. That way the first loop will copy from the returned value while the second loop will work correctly because it would be getting iterators off the same vector data member. Note that if you use this then for the second loop you would have to make `it` a `const_iterator`.

See the comments in the below modified program:

```
class stdHolder {

public:

  stdHolder();
//-----------------------v---------------------------------->return by const lvalue reference
  const std::vector<int> &getSV() const {return _myVector;}

private:

  std::vector<int> _myVector;

};

stdHolder::stdHolder() {

  _myVector.push_back(1);
  _myVector.push_back(2);
  _myVector.push_back(3);

}

int main() {

  stdHolder myHolder;

  //still works 
  std::vector<int> localSV = myHolder.getSV();
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = localSV.begin(); it != localSV.end(); it++ ) {
    std::cout << "printing " << *it + 100 << std::endl;
  }

  //this works too now
  //---------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvv--------------------------------------->const_iterator used instead of iterator
  for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = myHolder.getSV().begin(); it != myHolder.getSV().end(); it++ ) {
    std::cout << "                                 printing " << *it + 100 << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

Other option is to just add `begin` and `end` member function for your `stdHolder` and then you'll be able to use *range-based for loop*.

Comment: A reasonable fix might be to have `getSV` return by `const` reference. The first loop would copy from that returned value, while the latter loop would be okay because it would be getting iterators off the same reference to the same underlying `vector`. `const` isn't *required*, but it prevents punching holes in the interface that would allow users to arbitrarily modify a private member.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, but note that then for the second loop `it` should be changed to `const_iterator`. Just mentioning in case OP is not aware of this.

Comment: Sure. Though `auto` was basically invented to avoid that aggravation with declaring specific iterator types, so unless you're somehow constrained to pre-C++11 (I pity you if so), it's not something you typically need to worry about. (Of course, in this case, a plain for-each style loop would remove that headache too)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah, other option is to add `begin` and `end` member functions.

Comment: Remember that caching the result of `.end()` has big performance impacts because of function call overhead etc. So it would be wise to do so here too.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I had not realized the handling involved in calling twice my getSV(). Caching locally I do not like very much, so I think I will solve by letting my real code (this was of course an MWE) publish the pointer to the inside vector.

Comment: I learned something today! :-)